# Creating scripts

Tags: laptop, scripts, power-management, battery

I'm following advice from LessWatts to lower battery drain with the following commands:

```
mount -o remount,noatime /
hdparm -B 1 -S 12 /dev/sda
echo 3000 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
iwconfig wlan0 power on
echo 10 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

The question is, how do I set them up to start automatically with system start?

Comment: Put that in a scrip, make executable, copy to /etc/pm/power.d/ and /etc/pm/sleep.d/. I don't think the fourth command helps with power saving in any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can use the /etc/rc.local for a root boot script.

First copy all the commands into a text file, then append this line **at the top** of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

then save it somewhere, perhaps your home dir. ( /home/user/battery-script.sh )

Then make it executable, in terminal:

```
$ chmod +x /home/user/battery-script.sh
```

Now in terminal:

```
$ gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Now before the line `exit 0` write the path to your script. ( /home/user/battery-script.sh )
Make sure `exit 0` is after everything else, or else it will exit before executing the commands.

Now just to be sure of when the script is run, you will probably want to add an xmessage command so that a message pops up when it is run.

```
xmessage -center "Battery script run in /etc/rc.local"
```

make sure it's before the `exit 0`.

Now, reboot to test to make sure it runs on startup, then you can remove the xmessage line if it is satisfactory.

If this does not work for some reason, you can fall back to GNOME's autostart manager.  It involves editing the sudoers file to allow root access to your script without a password.  We will edit the file's permissions and ownership as to not create a security hole.

First, move the entire script into the /bin/ folder:

```
$ sudo mv battery-script.sh /bin/
```

set root ownership and permissions preventing a regular user from inserting malicious code to be run as root:

```
$ sudo chown root /bin/battery-script.sh
$ sudo chgrp root /bin/battery-script.sh
$ sudo chmod 555 /bin/battery-script.sh
```

Now that's set, time to edit the sudoers file:

```
$ gksudo gedit /etc/sudoers
```

Go to the bottom and add this line. Replace **$USER** with your username

```
$USER    ALL = NOPASSWD:/bin/battery-script.sh
```

Now you can run the script without a password when using sudo.

Next, open Startup Applications, click add.
Put anything under Name, and under command put:

```
sudo /bin/battery-script.sh
```

That's it! Your script will run as root when you boot up, you can add a line in the battery-script.sh `echo > /home/user/it_works.txt` (replace with username) and that file will be created upon the next boot so you can be sure it's working, or as mentioned earlier, you can use xmessage.

Comment: could you put that on pastebin.com instead so the formatting shows correctly?

Comment: sure, http://pastebin.com/URgS56d7

Comment: ah ok, sorry I use "[]" as parenthesis, so I did not mean to put them in the script. Now the question is do you get an xmessage alert when you reboot?  If no, check it manually in the terminal to make sure it's installed.  If yes, all you need to do is remove the brackets on the rc.local script.

Comment: basically type `xmessage test` to see if xmessage is installed. I thought it was installed by default, just making sure.

Comment: Also what Ubuntu version do you have? if you don't know do `lsb_release  -r` in terminal

Comment: hm, I'm not sure why it isn't working.. could you paste the output of `ls -l /etc/rc.local`?

Comment: yes. I looked into it a bit, and in short, please try this http://pastebin.com/tAGNfvQ2 for your rc.local; basically I'm hoping using the full paths of all commands will fix it. If not, then I do not know how to make rc.local work.  **however** I do know of another way to make this work.  Let me know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7682/discussion-between-matt-and-venem)

Comment: +1, however `sudo visudo` should really be the command used to edit the sudoers file instead of `gedit`.

Comment: well visudo is very confusing.  I never ran into problems, and I never use it.  Actually I use regular `vim`, but that too is confusing unless you already learned it.  so I figured `gedit` would be the easiest option.